# Ionic how to add button beside an image

Tags: css, image, button, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing a **Ionic 3 app** and I want an `button` with a `small add icon` beside the **image**. That looks like this.

[image]

Like the **small green add icon** beside the image.

Here is my **html** bellow for the image that I had done.

```
<ion-col col-4>
    <img [src]="image" [hidden]="!image">
    <img src="assets/imgs/avatar-placeholder.png" [hidden]="image">
  </ion-col>
```

and the **scss**

```
img {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

The result below of my image.

[image]

I just want the **small green add icon** like in the first image.

Appreciate if someone could help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` on the icon.

> An absolutely positioned element is an element whose computed position value is absolute or fixed.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}

div > .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.esparkinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/default-avatar.png" alt="">
  <img class="icon" src="https://findicons.com/files/icons/985/affel/128/add.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Worked for me! Instead of image I used **ionicons**